# Identifying the distribution of this data

Tags: poisson-distribution, distribution-identification

I'm working with a datetime series, and each observation is the count of occurrences per that period.  This sounds to me like these values would be Poisson distributed.  But my EDA has left me confused. What kind of distribution does this data fit?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a gamma distribution.  Something like Weibull?

Comment: @beerhunter. It's *counts* (i.e. discrete), including a fair number of exact 0's.

Comment: @ian are the data available (vs time)? What sort of model are you looking at? Generally you don't require the marginal distribution for modelling, only the conditional distribution (which may be less skew than the marginal; if there's a mix of different means, the Poisson may work better than this looks). An obvious simple model for counts with possible heterogeneity *within* each observation (rather than just across them) is negative binomial.  There isnt enough information to tell whether a Poisson is adequate though (it depends on what mix of conditional means you have in your fitted model)

Comment: @Ian Tavener: an you please post (a link to) the data? We cannot say much without seeing the data.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the data are red light camera violations for the city of Chicago found here:
https://www.kaggle.com/chicago/chicago-red-light-and-speed-camera-data#red-light-camera-violations.csv

I cleaned it first, so that each count is a sum from one camera for one date.